# what is the jinja2 equivalent of django add filter?

Tags: python, html, django-templates, jinja2

I am trying to render an html like below in jinja2

```
<div>
     <tr>
        <td>{{ row.a|add:b}}</td>
     </tr>
</div>
```

it throws error `expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'` . Above html was written for django template language. can someone help me with right substitute for jinja2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum` filter in jinja2
In your case `[a,b]|sum` should work

Check this: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#sum